# How to default Html.DropDownList to no selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, razor

I have the following dropdown populated by a ViewBag element:

`@Html.DropDownList("SelectedRole", ViewBag.Roles as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Currently, upon page load, the first element of the Roles list is displayed, however I want to default it to no selection (the dropdown should be blank on page load). My attempt was in jQuery as follows, but it did not have any effect on the dropdown default selection (still showed the first element of Roles):

`$("#SelectedRole").prop("selectedIndex", -1);`

Is there a way I could set the default within Razor itself? If not, through some other way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this syntax

`@Html.DropDownList("SelectedRole", ViewBag.Roles as List<SelectListItem>,"", new { @class = "form-control" })`

Note: I have added a `""` in the syntax.. this will be the first option in the dropdown. Hope this helps..

Comment: IMO this is probably the better/more maintainable of the two solutions as it does not depend on any additional client-side code to be added to your view.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an empty role to the `Roles` in your controller.
Otherwise you could achieve this client side like below:

```
$(function(){
     $('#SelectedRole').append( new Option("",-1,true,true) );
});
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('#SelectedRole').append( new Option("",-1,true,true) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectedRole">
    <option val="1">Red</option>
    <option val="2">Green</option>
    <option val="3">Blue</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I thought about that but wanted to do it from the front-end only if at all possible.

Comment: Of course it is possible. You could try something like that I suggest.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You can do this directly in Razor without having to use JS.  Edit: Looks like Reddy beat me to the example.

Comment: @ITWorker Thanks. I am glad that I helped.